# Question about finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra

We consider  $A$ an abelian $p$-group and we denote $A[m]=\{a\in A\mid am=0\}$.

If there exists $n>1$ such that 
$$
A[p]\cap (pA[p^2])\cap (p^2A[p^3])\cap\dots\cap (p^{n-1}A[p^{n}])=\{0\}
$$
does that implies that $A$ is finite?

Comment: Take $A=\Bbb Z$, any prime $p$ and any $n_0$ at all. It is abelian hence $p$-abelian, and $A[p]$ is $\{0\}$ already.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean ? do you mean that the implication is false ?

Comment: Yes because $\Bbb Z$ is infinite.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I'm pretty sure $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a $p$-group.

Comment: @egreg The OP said $p$-abelian, not $p$-group. Although it would make more sense indeed.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier And what $p$-abelian group should mean, if not “abelian $p$-group”?

Comment: Thanks for the edit,that is what I mean

Comment: @iskander If you consider for $A$ an infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then it satisfies the condition for $n=2$, because $A[p^2]=A$ and $pA=\{0\}$.

Comment: So do you mean that the implication is false ?

Comment: @egreg a $p$-abelian group is a group where $(xy)^p=x^py^p$ for any $x, y$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I suspected it, but the OP has clarified the doubt.

Answer (score 1):

If the group $A$ has finite exponent, that is, $p^mx=0$ for every $x$, then
$$
p^mA[p^{m+1}]=\{0\}
$$
Consider an infinite direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and you have a counterexample.

Comment: In fact  I want to prove the following result:

Let $p$ be a prime number and $A$ an abelian $p-$group. for $k\ge 1$ define 

$$\phi_k(A)=\bigcap_{n\ge k}p^{n-k}A[p^n]$$

where $A[m]=\{a\in A: am=0\}$



If $A$ is artinian we have :

$\phi_1(A)=\left\{0\right\}$ imply   $A$ is finite.     

Thanks for your help.

Comment: @iskander Well, it seems you have to take another road for your proof. `;-)` On the other hand, the structure of artinian abelian $p$-group is pretty well known, because they are the subgroups of finite direct sums of the Prüfer $p$-group.

Comment: Can you help me please ?   Thanks

Comment: @iskander The question has already been asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2652182/62967

Comment: I looked at it and there is no proof  ?

Comment: @iskander Please, ask it again, with more information about your thoughts than in that bad question.

Comment: I posted the question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656225/artinian-imply-finite