# Artinian imply finite

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let  $A$ be  an abelian $p$-group and let's denote $A[m]=\{a\in A\mid am=0\}$.

If there exists $n>1$ such that 
$$
A[p]\cap (pA[p^2])\cap (p^2A[p^3])\cap\dots\cap (p^{n-1}A[p^{n}])=\{0\}
$$
does that implies that $A$ is finite?

This is the full problem that I am trying to solve, I already solved question a) and b) but I don't know how to solve part c). Would you please help me to do so. Thanks[image]

Comment: I think you forgot a hypothesis, otherwise it's the same question as before.

Comment: @egreg, I edited the question, could you please help me to answer part c) of the problem?        thanks